How do I configure the network manager to use a custom PAC file?
Disclaimer: I don't have much proxy experience, so I may be missing something obvious. I have tried to do my due diligence before asking.
Short Version - Basic Question
I'm having an issue specifying a local file as the "Automatic" Configuration URL in Settings -> Network -> Proxy.
I've verified that if I use "Manual" and then enter the IP address / port of the proxy server, my traffic is correctly routed through the proxy, but that routes all traffic through the proxy, and I only want to do it for specific sites. From what I understand the best way to do this is with a PAC file. I've written one which I think is valid, and saved it to: $HOME/.config/custom_proxy/my-proxy.js. In the "Configuration URL", I've tried setting it to several values, but none of them "work". I've tried:
file:///home/joncrall/.config/custom_proxy/my-proxy.js
file://localhost/home/joncrall/.config/custom_proxy/my-proxy.js
/home/joncrall/.config/custom_proxy/my-proxy.js

I just want to have the PAC file live somewhere on my local disk. Am I specifying it incorrectly?
Long Version - Motivation and Question
The motivating use case is that I have a VPN on my laptop, and I'm working on my desktop, which does not have a VPN. Both my laptop and desktop are on the same LAN. I want specific sites to have their traffic routed through the laptop, so they effectively use the VPN, but everything else I want to just use a direct connection. From what I understand this is a classic case for a proxy.
On my laptop, I'm running the command ssh -N -D 0.0.0.0:1080 localhost, which I believe turns it into a proxy server. I think this is all I need to do on the laptop side, other than ensure that it's on and connected to the VPN.
On my desktop (which is the proxy client), I've written a PAC file as follows:
    echo '
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    var socks_proxy = "SOCKS 192.168.1.3:1080";
    if (shExpMatch(host, "*.special-site1.com")) {
        return socks_proxy;
    }
    else if (shExpMatch(host, "*.special-site2.net")) {
        return socks_proxy;
    }
    else if (shExpMatch(host, "special-site1.com")) {
        return socks_proxy;
    }
    return "DIRECT";
}
    ' > "$HOME"/.config/custom_proxy/my-proxy.js

To point Ubuntu's network manager at this PAC file, I did GUI navigation:
Settings -> Network -> Proxy

Enabled "Network Proxy"
Changed Configuration to "Automatic"
Entered the URI: file:///home/joncrall/.config/custom_proxy/my-proxy.js
Clicked Save.
This did not work. I tried navigating to a site behind the VPN, and the DNS probe failed.
I also tried alternate ways to specify the URI:

file:///home/joncrall/.config/custom_proxy/my-proxy.js
file://localhost/home/joncrall/.config/custom_proxy/my-proxy.js
/home/joncrall/.config/custom_proxy/my-proxy.js

None of these worked.
Debugging Steps Taken
If I change Configuration to "Manual", and then under "SOCKS Host" entered the
URL: 192.168.1.3 and Port: 1080, and leaving the http, https, ftp, and ignored host settings alone, does seem to work. I was able to get to the site in question. But this method is to heavy. It routes all traffic, and I want a little more control, so only some sites go through the proxy.
I'm not sure what's wrong with my PAC file. I've verified that this seems to be valid syntax that does what I want using pacparser:
    python -c "if 1:
        import pacparser
        pacparser.init()
        pacparser.parse_pac('/home/joncrall/.config/custom_proxy/my-proxy.js')
        print(pacparser.find_proxy('http://www.google.com', 'www.google.com'))
        print(pacparser.find_proxy('https://subdomain.special-site1.com/foobar'))
        print(pacparser.find_proxy('https://special-site1.com'))
        print(pacparser.find_proxy('https://special-site2.net'))
        print(pacparser.find_proxy('https://foo.special-site2.net'))
    "

It prints:
DIRECT
SOCKS 192.168.1.3:1080
SOCKS 192.168.1.3:1080
DIRECT
SOCKS 192.168.1.3:1080

which is what I would expect. It passes through the two sites that are not in the list, and the other it returns the address to the proxy.
I've also tried exposing my custom my-proxy.js via an http server. To start the server I ran:
    cd "$HOME"/.config/custom_proxy/
    sudo python3 -m http.server 80

And then I modified the "Configuration URL" via:
    gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy autoconfig-url "http://localhost/my-proxy.js"

Doing that did cause printouts in my python http server, indicating that something did a GET on the my-proxy.js file. That indicates that the network manager is reading the PAC file, but it does not appear to be routing traffic correct.
I'm wondering if there is any way I can do print-debugging inside the PAC file itself? Or is there any way I can check that the network manager is attempting to use it?
System Info:
I am on Ubuntu 24.04.
The references I've looked at trying to find an answer are:

https://serverfault.com/questions/62261/can-i-configure-ubuntu-to-use-a-proxy-for-a-subset-of-websites
https://findproxyforurl.com/pac-functions/
https://gist.github.com/swinton/5a66c283fd011af7f67a
How to make my proxy settings change depending on the network I connect to?
https://superuser.com/questions/191037/local-pac-file-url-format-that-works-with-ie-and-safari-windows
https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/ProxyAutoConfig
https://github.com/manugarg/pacparser

But I'm having a hard time. Is there something wrong in how I specified the PAC file, or the contents of it?

Your question is asking about how to configure a PAC file. Let's start with what it is that you're trying to actually do.
According to Proxy auto-config on Wikipedia:

A proxy auto-config (PAC) file defines how web browsers and other user
agents can automatically choose the appropriate proxy server (access
method) for fetching a given URL.

So this means that a PAC file allows the browser or other agent to choose a particular proxy server automatically based on some predefined functions and environment conditions. These conditions can vary from specific hostnames, IP addresses, or even time-based conditions.
Additionally, the PAC file conditional returns a string in a specific return value format. This string is formatted as either DIRECT, PROXY, SOCKS, HTTP, HTTPS, SOCKS4, or SOCKS5.
Thus, when I examine your PAC file, you specify a SOCKS return value format when the condition is a shExpMatch that matches one of several hosts. Otherwise, it will return DIRECT.
To solve your problem, let's start by taking the PAC file out of the equation and setup a simple SSH SOCKS tunnel to a server that will be our proxy server. After this is configured and working, we will change your setup to automatically choose a proxy server based on your PAC file conditionals.

Setup SSH SOCKS Tunnel
The basic instructions for setting up a SSH SOCKS tunnel is outlined in an article on Linuxize titled, How to Set up SSH SOCKS Tunnel for Private Browsing.
The prerequisites are a server and a client.
Server

Any flavor of Linux
openssh-server installed
sshd running on some port, typically port 22
Access to the server on the specified port from the internet, typically port 22
Access to the internet

Client

openssh-client installed
Access to the internet

Create Tunnel
At this point, to create a SSH SOCKS Tunnel is very easy with the following command, which is run on the client.
ssh -D 8080 [USER]@[SERVER_IP]

This will create a SSH connection to the server and a SOCKS tunnel on port 8080. This means that traffic on the client that is directed to 127.0.0.1 and port 8080 will be redirected to the server.
Per the ssh(1) man page:
-D [bind_address:]port
        Specifies a local “dynamic” application-level port
        forwarding.  This works by allocating a socket to listen
        to port on the local side, optionally bound to the
        specified bind_address.  Whenever a connection is made to
        this port, the connection is forwarded over the secure
        channel, and the application protocol is then used to
        determine where to connect to from the remote machine.
        Currently the SOCKS4 and SOCKS5 protocols are supported,
        and will act as a SOCKS server.  Only root can forward
        privileged ports.  Dynamic port forwardings can also be
        specified in the configuration file.

Other appropriate options you can add to the ssh command are -f and -N.
-f      Requests to go to background just before command
        execution.  This is useful if is going to ask for
        passwords or passphrases, but the user wants it in the
        background.  This implies -n.  The recommended way to
       start X11 programs at a remote site is with something
        like ssh -f host xterm.

-N      Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just
        forwarding ports.  Refer to the description of
        SessionType in ssh_config(5) for details.

Take note: There is nothing to do on the server. As long as you are able to ssh into it, you will be able to create a SSH SOCKS Tunnel and treat the server as a proxy.
Setup Browser
There are two ways to configure the browser to use the SOCKS Proxy. One is to manually specify the SOCKS Proxy. The other is with the Gnome System Network Settings and then configuring Firefox to use the System Settings. I'll outline both.
OPTION 1: Manually Specify SOCKS Proxy in Firefox
To configure the browser to manually specify a SOCKS Proxy, do the following:

In Firefox, go to General/Network Settings/Settings, select Manual Proxy, and enter 127.0.0.1 for SOCKS Host and 8080 for Port.
Check the radio box for SOCKS v5.
Check the box next to Proxy DNS when using SOCKS 5. This will send any DNS queries down the tunnel as well. Click OK to complete.


Your SSH SOCKS Tunnel should be setup and functioning. All traffic will be directed through the SSH SOCKS Tunnel to your server and out to the internet from that network.
If you go to https://whatismyipaddress.com/, this should confirm that your IP address is the public IP of your proxy server and not of your client. You can change your browser settings back to No Proxy and look again at https://whatismyipaddress.com/ to confirm that they're different.

If you kill the SSH connection, you'll get an error in your client browser saying The proxy server is refusing connections.
If the SSH connection and tunnel are started but you still don't have internet access from your client browser, then there is a problem with your server not having internet access. Go back to the beginning and confirm that your server can reach the internet.

OPTION 2: Configure Firefox to use Gnome System Settings
Alternatively, you can configure the SOCKS Proxy within Gnome System Settings. To do so, first open Gnome Settings/Network/Network Proxy, select Manual for the proxy Configuration, and enter 127.0.0.1 for the SOCKS Host URL and 8080 for the SOCKS Host Port. Next, delete localhost, 127.0.0.0/8, ::1 in the Ignored Hosts field (or just localhost). Finally, click Save.


Then in Firefox, go to General/Network Settings/Settings and select Use system proxy settings.


Setup PAC file for Proxy Auto-Configuration
To switch over to automatically choosing a proxy server with a PAC file is as easy as changing the settings in your browser and/or Gnome System Settings to use the PAC file instead of manually specifying a SOCKS Proxy for all traffic.
Take note: If you can't get the SSH SOCKS Tunnel working to your proxy server, then the setup of automatically choosing a proxy server to use your proxy server won't work. So get the SSH SOCKS Tunnel working first. Then switch to automatic with the PAC file.
Let's start with the file...
In your question, you created a file called my-proxy.js. In my example below, I've renamed it to proxy.pac and placed it in my home directory: /home/mike/proxy.pac.
According to the Mozilla documentation for the Proxy Auto-Configuration (PAC) file, the PAC file should be named with a .pac extension. But in my testing, this isn't mandatory since I was successful using a .js extension as you did.

The auto-config file should be saved to a file with a .pac filename
extension: proxy.pac.

Configuration
As before when you setup a SOCKS Proxy for all traffic, the configuration to set the PAC file can be done in two ways.
In both options, the format for the URL is the same:
file:///home/mike/proxy.pac

OPTION 1: Manually specify PAC file in Firefox
In Firefox, go to General/Network Settings/Settings and enter file:///home/mike/proxy.pac in the Automatic proxy configuration URL field. I found that by simply clicking OK and closing the settings window, this would work. But you may find that you'll need to close and re-load the browser entirely, particularly the first time you set the URL. Subsequent changes and a Reload were sufficient for me to see any changes take effect.

OPTION 2: Configure Firefox to use Gnome System Settings
Alternatively, you can configure the SOCKS Proxy within Gnome System Settings. To do so, first open Gnome Settings/Network/Network Proxy, select Automatic for the proxy Configuration, and enter file:///home/mike/proxy.pac for the Configuration URL.

Then in Firefox, go to General/Network Settings/Settings and select Use system proxy settings.


Testing
This was tested on Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop. A SSH SOCKS Tunnel was created to a personal server with the following command. This was run on the client machine.
ssh -D 8080 [USER]@[SERVER_IP]

The exact .pac file I used for testing was as follows:
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
    var socks_proxy = "SOCKS 127.0.0.1:8080";
    if (shExpMatch(host, "*.askubuntu.com")) {
        return socks_proxy;
    }
    return "DIRECT";
}

I confirmed by running tcpdump -n net 172.64.150 on the proxy server. The IP subnet was gathered by running nslookup askubuntu.com on the proxy server.
$ nslookup askubuntu.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   askubuntu.com
Address: 172.64.150.156
Name:   askubuntu.com
Address: 104.18.37.100

During testing with this configuration, traffic to askubuntu.com was directed to my proxy server. All other traffic was not.
Another simple test is to kill your ssh connection. In this situation, you won't be able to access askubuntu.com.

I'm having trouble reproducing this. I'm attempting to follow your instructions exactly. On which machine was your ssh -D command run? Your local machine, or the proxy server? It looks like a local command, did you also have an ssh -D command on the proxy server? I ran tcpdump on my local and proxy. I don't see any output from the tcpdump command on my proxy, but I do see it on my local.

Is it possible to make the pac file write to some log file to disk so I can be sure that it's even getting called? Maybe I need to setup a server that writes log files and then call that server from the pac file? I'm also finding that nslookup google.com returns different results depending on where I run it, which makes testing this harder.

I attempted to use a "fetch" command in the pac file to send a POST to a python server I started on "0.0.0.0:8000", but perhaps pac files don't support fetch? After enabling the automatic proxy in firefox and the system I don't see any logs indicating that it is posting to my dummy web service.

@Erotemic You run ssh -D 8080 user@proxyserver on your local machine. This creates the connection on your local machine to the proxy server to listen on port 8080. No need to run anything on the server.

@Erotemic I’m not sure how to set up the logging as you’ve requested. I’ll look into it and see what I find. As for nslookup google.com, it’s true that the IP changes a lot. So maybe try a website that doesn’t. I used my website during testing as well, which doesnt change IP addresses. But I didn’t want to use my website in the answer, because I didn’t want it to seem like I was promoting it or anything.

I tried both variants with and without an ssh command running on the server. I will try again tomorrow on 22.04 (downgrading from 24.04). Hard to provide a report of steps taken in this format. I made a GIST that outlines how I attempted to add logging to the PAC file. I was able to run a server on localhost that accepts and logs POST requests, but I don't know if I'm calling it correctly from the PAC file.
https://gist.github.com/Erotemic/94b1e0a84f304b879913e58bb09efb92

I've downgraded to 22.04 and attempted to reproduce your steps, replacing google.com for mlb.com I've scripted out the exact steps I took with notes on any manual steps taken: https://gist.github.com/Erotemic/948ec634c2de011b22e5b0d30af3d957
But I only see tcpdump output on the local machine, never the proxy. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

@Erotemic I updated my answer with more info

Thank you for the writeup. I think the answer needs to be tweaked before it is marked as correct. But I've awarded you the bounty, as it helped me get a detailed understanding of what was going on. I learned enough to spot the problem. I've recorded my debugging steps in: https://gist.github.com/Erotemic/3a914be82b217260442e3fbc10299b20
I think it comes down to needing an addition "askubuntu.com" pattern to match. The leading "*." seems broken. It is still unclear to me if the system settings are doing anything, but firefox is respecting the pac file.
